# Tor connection issue with proxychains

Tags: configuration

So I'm new to learning tor and proxychains and while I was trying to figure out why proxychains aren't working, I think there's issue with connecting to tor.

```
tor service status
Sep 24 20:43:49.265 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.31 as libc.
Sep 24 20:43:49.266 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 24 20:43:49.266 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 24 20:43:49.266 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'service'.  Failing.
Sep 24 20:43:49.266 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Proxychains config file (lines without #)

```
dynamic_chain

Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns
#remote_dns_subnet 10
remote_dns_subnet 224

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
```

no changes made to /etc/tor/torrc

commands used

```
service tor start                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(user㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ tor service status       
Sep 26 22:46:47.161 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.31 as libc.
Sep 26 22:46:47.162 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 26 22:46:47.162 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 26 22:46:47.162 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'service'.  Failing.
Sep 26 22:46:47.162 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(user㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ proxychains firefox www.whatismyip.com                                                                                                                                                                                               1 ⨯
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
```

tor.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/tor/torrc` file?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to that file, can you help me please. I'm using Kali on Vmware

Comment: by the way /etc/tor/torrc, it's all commented

Comment: it depends on what exactly do you want to do: run something through Tor via proxychains or run Tor iself through it? Can you please clarify the task and post all the configs **and** the command lines for running them both? It will help me to help you

Comment: Thank you, let me the edit the question and yes I want to use Tor via proxychains.

Comment: please examine the ExecStart line for your Tor service file - looks like another `torrc` file is used. Post the line here, please - looks like it's the key to your problem, all the rest looks fine for me

Comment: I've updated the question and mentioned about ExecStart line, can you please tell me if it's okay or do I need to make any changes

Comment: I see the problem :) It's a Debian-style tor setup. Look for the service named like tor@0 or similar - at your systemd folders. It contains **actual** Tor service file with the **separate** torrc - find it and post it. The name can be seen most of the times in the tree output of `systemctl status` command

Comment: Thank you Alexey.
I guess uninstall and re-install is the best debug method, it's working now.